# Parsing xml file cant select node

Tags: c#, .net, xml, parsing

I have to load an xml file with the following contents I added the root nood view as I no an xml file cant have two parents but no matter what I do using the following I cant selec the path to get this function to work. This is using C# .net 4

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"XMLFile.XML");

            XmlDocument currentDocument = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                currentDocument.LoadXml(text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            string path = "View/Data";
            XmlNodeList nodeList = currentDocument.SelectNodes(path);
            IDictionary<string, string> keyValuePairList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode innerNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (innerNode.Attributes != null && innerNode.Attributes.Count == 2)
                    {
                        keyValuePairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(innerNode.Attributes[0].Value, innerNode.Attributes[1].Value));
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in keyValuePairList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Xml File Contents

```
<view>
 <Data>
    <Adapters>
      <Adapter AdapterName="dataportal:EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess.DataAdapters.EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter AdapterName="viewframework://Adapters/AdvancedList">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework.AdvancedListSupportAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter AdapterName="omsdk://Adapters/Criteria">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess.DataAdapters.SdkCriteriaAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
    </Adapters>
    <ItemsSource>
      <AdvancedListSupportClass xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" DataTypeName="" AdapterName="viewframework://Adapters/AdvancedList" FullUpdateAdapter="dataportal:EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter" DataSource="mom:ManagementGroup" IsRecurring="True" RecurrenceFrequency="{x:Static s:Int32.MaxValue}" FullUpdateFrequency="1" Streaming="true">
        <AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
          <QueryParameter Parameter="TypeProjectionId" Value="$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$"/>
        </AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
      </AdvancedListSupportClass>
    </ItemsSource>
    <Criteria>
      <QueryCriteria xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Criteria.xsd" Adapter="omsdk://Adapters/Criteria">
        <Criteria>
          <FreeformCriteria>
            <Freeform>
              <Criteria xmlns="http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/">
                <Expression>
                  <And>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/TierQueue$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="IncidentTierQueuesEnum.Tier2"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Resolved"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Closed"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <UnaryExpression>
                        <ValueExpression>
                          <GenericProperty Path="$Context/Path[Relationship='WorkItem!System.WorkItemAssignedToUser' SeedRole='Source']$">Id</GenericProperty>
                        </ValueExpression>
                        <Operator>IsNull</Operator>
                      </UnaryExpression>
                    </Expression>
                  </And>
                </Expression>
              </Criteria>
            </Freeform>
          </FreeformCriteria>
        </Criteria>
      </QueryCriteria>
    </Criteria>
  </Data>
    <Presentation>
    <Columns>
      <mux:ColumnCollection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mux="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/Common/UI/Views/GridView" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:datebinding="clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Extensions;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Extensions">
        <mux:Column Name="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Id" Property="Id$ReturnValueAsBigInt$" DataType="s:String"/>
        <mux:Column Name="title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" Width="200" DisplayName="Header_Title" Property="Title" DataType="s:String"/>
        <mux:Column Name="sDisplayName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status.DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Status" Property="Status.DisplayName" DataType="s:String"/>
        <mux:Column Name="priority" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Priority, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Priority" Property="Priority" DataType="s:Int32"/>
        <mux:Column Name="targetTime" DisplayMemberBinding="{datebinding:DateBinding Path=TargetResolutionTime, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Target_Resolution_Time" Property="TargetResolutionTime" DataType="s:DateTime"/>
        <mux:Column Name="aDisplayName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AffectedUser.DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Affected_User" Property="AffectedUser.DisplayName" DataType="s:String"/>
        <mux:Column Name="lastModified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=$LastModified$, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Last_Modified" Property="$LastModified$" DataType="s:DateTime"/>
      </mux:ColumnCollection>
    </Columns>
    <ViewStrings>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Id">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Id"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Title">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Title"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Status">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Status"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Priority">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Priority"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Target_Resolution_Time">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Target_Resolution_Time"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Affected_User">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Affected_User"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Last_Modified">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Last_Modified"]$</ViewString>
    </ViewStrings>
  </Presentation>
</view>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `/` in your path to make it absolute

```
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"XMLFile.XML");

            XmlDocument currentDocument = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                currentDocument.LoadXml(text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            string path = "//*"; // retieve all data
            XmlNodeList nodeList = currentDocument.SelectNodes(path);
            IDictionary<string, string> keyValuePairList = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode innerNode in node.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (innerNode.Attributes != null && innerNode.Attributes.Count == 2)
                    {
                        keyValuePairList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(innerNode.Attributes[0].Value, innerNode.Attributes[1].Value));
                    }
                }
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in keyValuePairList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} : {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: it only bringing back one element i think i need to go to adapaters but what do i do about presentation at the bottom?

Comment: what you need to retrieve all data or just first node

Comment: all data into key value pair

Answer (score 0):

You're forgetting the first slash in your path:

```
string path = "/View/Data";
```

The first slash denotes an **absolute** path. If you omit it, you're saying "select `View/Data` based on the **current** matched node", it's the same as `./View/Data`. But since you have no node selected at that point, it doesn't return anything.

To return all the Data nodes, you can use the `//` descendant selector:

```
"//Data"
```

To select **all** elements except the root, use `*` in combination with `//`:

```
"//*"
```

Comment: Its still not bringing back all the data all i want to be able to do is bring back all the key values pairs into a dictoary object it shouldnt be that hard should it ?

Comment: @DavidBuckley so you want _all_ the nodes or just `data` nodes or..?

Comment: all nodes and data yes so can have in a dictonary or is their a way to get a strongly typed object not using xsd.exer

Comment: @DavidBuckley It's really unclear what you are asking though. You seem confused in the sense that "XML" and a "key-value collection" are entirely different data structures. If you want to transform them into each other you need to say what the key and the value are, respectively...

Comment: Sorry i got claifarcation from my senior in office i only need to get these from the xml  /View/Data/ItemsSource
  
 /View/Data/Criteria
 11:32